# Django - get_context_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I am trying to add inlineformset to the Django Blog project. I got post and I want to add multiple images to the post via Class Based Views. But when I am trying to get_context_data I receive this error:

get_context_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

Forms.py

```
class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Post
         fields = ['title' , 'content' ]

PostImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Post, PostImage, fields=['image', 'description'], exclude=['post'] , max_num=30, extra=3)
```

Views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

     form_class = CreatePostForm
     template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'

     def get_context_data(self, form):
         context = super(PostCreateView. self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         if self.request.POST:
             context['post_images'] = PostImageFormSet(self.request.POST)
         else:
             context['post_images'] = PostImageFormSet()
         return context

      def form_valid(self, form):
          context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
          formset = context['post_images']
          form.instance.author = self.request.user
          if formset.is_valid():
              response = super().form_valid(form)
              formset.instance = self.object
              formset.save()
              return response
          else:
              return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Any idea why I am receiving this kind of error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `form` parameter. The form is never used in the `get_context_data` anyway:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
     form_class = CreatePostForm
     template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'

     def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
         context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
         if self.request.POST:
             context['post_images'] = PostImageFormSet(self.request.POST)
         else:
             context['post_images'] = PostImageFormSet()
         return context

      def form_valid(self, form):
          context = self.get_context_data()
          formset = context['post_images']
          form.instance.author = self.request.user
          if formset.is_valid():
              response = super().form_valid(form)
              formset.instance = self.object
              formset.save()
              return response
          else:
              return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: you changed OP's line `context = super(PostCreateView. self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` to `context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)`, what is the difference between specifying the current class view name and not doing it ?

Comment: @Elias: the two are equivalent, but the advantage of not naming the base-class is that you can easily copy paste it to somewhere else. Since Python-3.x, naming the base class is no longer necessary.